# Rotation value of image as its dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have an image of an arrow that the user can rotate by clicking and dragging it.

Using jQuery or Js, how could I get the rotation value (in degrees) as it's being dragged?

I tried `$('.el').css("-moz-transform")` but all I get is a matrix of values I cant really use: `matrix(0.721445, 0.190526, -0.190526, 0.721445, 0px, 0px)`

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lad6q3sk/

Comment: You can get a rotation degree from the transformation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the actual transform style like this:

```
$('.draggable_wp')[0].style.transform;
```

Which will return something like:

```
"rotate(-17.2931deg)"
```